# SQL Server Management Studio (18.7.1) file explorer keeps crashing

Tags: sql-server

I have just started having a problem with SSMS (18.7.1) where, when trying to Open or Save a file, the file explorer window is hung up waiting for Windows Installer to install something, and this never appears to succeed:

[Broken window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOaf6.png)

I've left the window open for 10 minutes to no avail, and even when clicking cancel, 10 minutes later there is still no change.

I am able to Open and Save from other programs successfully, and the main File Explorer works normally.

I've tried uninstalling/restarting/installing, as well as removing all extensions I had installed, but no luck and I've run out of things to try.

Any ideas of things to try would be much appreciated, before I decide to just do a Windows 10 re-install.

Comment: Did you try running SSMS as administrator? Not sure, Just a thought.

Comment: Just tried that, still no luck